# What's the best way to handle "type" tables with LINQ to SQL?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, enums

I have some tables that represent various types. They usually just consist of an ID (int), and a name. Ideally I would have this in an enum. Is there a way to map a table like this onto an enum?

EDIT: How would I handle it if there were extra fields other than an ID and Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just an id and a name, I generally do this:

```
public enum FootScent : int
{
Unknown = 0,
Mild = 1,
Sweaty =2,
SteppedInSomething = 3
}
```

and then on the LINQ entity property:

```
[Column("foot_scent_id", DbType = "Int NOT NULL")]
public FootScent Scent { get; set; }
```

For lookup tables with columns other than "id" and "name" that are needed, I usually just make a normal LINQ entity for them, though depending on your implementation it would probably be worth caching these to minimize trips to the DB.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have a custom class as a column type? For instance, if I had a FootScent class, and then the subclasses FootScentUnknown, FootScentMild, etc?

Comment: You can, but I believe it's a little more complicated and involves lazy-loading. I'd rather just use the id, and keep a dictionary (Dictionary<Int32, FootScent>) cached. Then you can added a (non-linq) property that just returns the FootScent object based on the FootScentId property (linq)

Comment: How would the caching be implemented? I've never done anything like that. I'm still pretty new to LINQ.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about keeping the cache within the FootScent class as a static variable? I would have to instantiate a data context to retrieve the values? Is there some way I can use the data context instance that was used to retrieve the FootScent instance instead of declaring new one?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you're caching in a web app, you'd want to use HttpContext.Cache. If you're caching in a client app, then I'd use a static class (name it Cached or something, and you can put anything else you cache in there). Persisting a DataContext in general is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the approach I'm going to try.